# Batch file doesnt want to be 'START'ed

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

I searched through the site and tried some things out but I can't solve the problem. It's like this:
I want to start two Batch Files from another Batch File.

```
START %ScriptAlarmDrive%
//Also tried CALL %ScriptAlarmDrive% (with EXIT /B in Alarm then)
CALL %ScriptBackupDrive%
```

When I start the Alarm Batch or the Backup Batch alone they work perfectly.

```
IF %Month% == 7 goto EchoExams
IF %Month% == 9 goto EchoNewSemester
EXIT

:EchoExams
ECHO -----Klausurentermine:
TYPE %SOURCEEXAMS% |more
ECHO. & ECHO. & PAUSE & EXIT

:EchoNewSemester
ECHO -----Im neuen Semester zu beachten:
TYPE %SourceNewSemesterTakeNote% |more
ECHO. & ECHO.
ECHO -----Informationen zum neuen Semester:
TYPE %SourceNewSemesterInformation% |more
ECHO. & ECHO. & PAUSE & EXIT
```

And the Backup Batch-File:

```
ECHO -----Backup
XCOPY %SOURCE% %DEST% %PARA%
ECHO. enter code here
```

But if I start the first Batch file only the Backup is executed and I don't get an output from the Alarm.

I would be grateful if someone could help me.
Moe

Comment: I do not see where you are assigning the variables **%ScriptAlarmDrive%** and **%ScriptBackupDrive%**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use `start` to run the two batch files at the same time. You would use `call` to run them sequentially (because they are batch files). There is no need for `exit /b` as a batch exits at the end anyway.

```
Starting a Program
===============

See start /? and call /? for help on all three ways.

Specify a program name
--------------------------------

    c:\windows\notepad.exe

In a batch file the batch will wait for the program to exit. When
typed the command prompt does not wait for graphical
programs to exit.

If the program is a batch file control is transferred and the rest of the calling batch file is not executed.

Use Start command
--------------------------

    start "" c:\windows\notepad.exe

Start starts a program and does not wait. Console programs start in a new window. Using the /b switch forces console programs into the same window, which negates the main purpose of Start.

Start uses the Windows graphical shell - same as typing in WinKey + R (Run dialog). Try 

    start shell:cache

Use Call command
-------------------------

Call is used to start batch files and wait for them to exit and continue the current batch file.
```

Comment: Okay thanks for the information.
It's just that I wanted to share the information with you that I tried something out which also didnt help.
And if possible I still want to START the Alaram but CALL the Backup file

Comment: So you want them running at the same time?

Comment: Yes. The Backup can run without me taking note of it but I want to see what the alarm tells me.

Comment: If `%ScriptAlarmDrive%` contains quotes it won't work. Show the full code.

Comment: Thank you it works perfectly now.
That was exactly my problem.

Comment: @Moe, this is why showing all your code is important.  I would have to say 50% of the problems we have to troubleshoot for people is caused by code they think is not the problem and they feel they do not have to post it to solve their problem. Going forward please post all your code. Which is why I asked to see the variable assignments.

Answer (score 0):

You can call those two `.bat` scripts from one `.bat` script.

Copy the script below and paste it into `CALL.bat`

```
CALL AlarmBatch.bat
CALL BackupBatch.bat
```

Name the two scripts you have `AlarmBatch.bat` and `BackupBatch.bat`
Make sure that these scripts are all in the same folder then run `CALL.bat`

also check [this](http://ss64.com/nt/call.html) and [this](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/call.php). It's all to do with `call`.

Comment: I have found the solution. The problem was that it didnt accept the variable in which I stored the destination of the Batch FIle...
Now it's like this and is working perfectly:

        START D:\Skripte\alarm.bat
        CALL %ScriptBackupDrive%